Common basis for all Lp spaces
Consider $B$ a bounded domain. I want to know if the eigenfunction of the Laplacian which vanish at the boundary form a basis for all $L^p(B)$  spaces. I know that they form a basis for $L^2$ and $H^1$ but what about $L^p(B)$?
